# I am moving a JLabel in a timer, but it is moving in the wrong direction

Tags: java, timer, jlabel

In the `actionListener` for a `JButton` on a `JFrame`, is the call to this method below. When `victim==playerTwo`, it correctly. However, when `victim==playerOne`, the `JLabel` pic moves the wrong direction. In the first scenario, the `JLabel` is supposed to move to the right, and to the left in the second. Please let me know if you have any questions, and thank you for any help you can provide.

```
if(victim==playerTwo)
        {
            ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() 
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
                {
                    if(pic.getLocationOnScreen().x>1300)
                    {
                        ((Timer)evt.getSource()).stop();
                    }
                    pic.setIcon(icon);
                    pic.setLocation((pic.getLocationOnScreen().x+5),45);
                }
            };
            new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
        }
        else
        {
            pic.setLocation(1000,500);

            ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() 
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
                {
                    if(pic.getLocationOnScreen().x<0)
                    {
                        ((Timer)evt.getSource()).stop();
                    }
                    pic.setIcon(icon);
                    pic.setLocation(((pic.getLocationOnScreen().x)-5),500);
                }
            };
            new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
        }
```

Comment: It was there i promise

Comment: I assume you've already verified it's hitting the `else` block (please verify if you haven't) - What do you get when you add debugging statements outputting `pic.getLocationOnScreen().x` during every timer tick? With just this code I don't see any obvious issues..

Comment: yes, the pictures shows up at the new location, it just moves as if it said +5 for the coordinates instead of -5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing up usage of [`getLocation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocation()) and [`getLocationOnScreen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocationOnScreen())

- `getLocation` uses coordinates relative to the **parent component**
- `getLocationOnScreen` uses coordinates relative to the **screen**

This is the type of issue that becomes more obvious moving your application around the screen.

Changing your code to stick to parent coordinate system should solve this:

```
pic.setLocation(((pic.getLocation().x)-5),500); // or +5 for player2
```